# Showing Dependence of Linear Combinations of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise problem in the book Linear Algebra by Larry Smith, $3^{rd}$ Edition. Given 4 vectors A, B, C and D in a vector Space V, we must show that the following 4 vectors in V are linear dependent:

$v_1 = A + B + C + D, v_2 = 2A + 2B + C - D, v_3 = A - B + C$ and $v_4 = A - C + D$

These vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ are linear combinations of the above 4. Also, there is no information about the dependence of the vectors A, B C and D.

I tried using the relation $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4=0$ and solving for the co-efficients $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ but that did not work.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w_1=A,...,w_4 = D$ for notational convenience.

We can write $v_k = \sum_i [M]_{ik} w_i$, where $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Since $\det M  = -13 $ we see that $M$ is invertible.

It is straightforward to check that $w_i = \sum_k [M^{-1}]_{ki} v_k$.

In particular, we see that if $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k = 0$ then $\sum_i \beta_i w_i = 0$ where $\beta = M \alpha$.

Similarly
if $\sum_i \beta_i w_i = 0$ then $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k = 0$  where $\beta = M \alpha$.

Hence if the $v_k$ are linearly dependent then so are the $w_i$ and vice bersa.

Comment: So you mean to say that only if A, B , C and D are dependent then we can say that the combinations will also be dependent. Okay. Getting it!!!

Comment: That is correct. In fact if and only if

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Suppose that $V=\Bbb R^4$, that $A=(1,0,0,0)$, that $B=(0,1,0,0)$, that $C=(0,0,1,0)$, and that $D=(0,0,0,1)$. Then

- $A+B+C+D=(1,1,1,1)$;
- $2A+2B+C-D=(2,2,1,-1)$;
- $A-B+C=(1,-1,1,0)$;
- $A-C+D=(1,0,-1,0)$.

And these four vectors are linearly *independent*, since$$\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{vmatrix}=-13\ne0.$$